# what is the meaning of 'later' here or there is any misprint?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Bose had his eye on the result of the action. When war clouds
> hung over Europe, he saw the situation as an opportunity to
> take advantage of the British weakness. He believed in seizing
> whatever opportunity was available to carry forward the
> struggle for freedom. He openly criticised the British for
> professing to fight for the freedom of the European nations
> under Nazi control but refusing to grant independence to its
> own colonies, including India. He had no compunction in
> taking the help of the Nazis or the Fascists and **later** of
> Imperial Japan—the ‘Axis powers’ as they came to be called
> when the war broke out—even though he believed in freedom
> and equality and other liberal ideals and disapproved of the
> arrogant racialism of the Nazis and the suppression of
> democratic institutions in Nazi Germany (as his writings
> show). However, he admired the Nazis and the Fascists for
> their discipline. Bose’s supporters point out that his
> association with Germany and Japan was dictated by
> revolutionary strategy and not by ideological kinship. In other
> words, he was just a pragmatist; he was against the Fascist
> theory of racial superiority and the Fascist acceptance of
> capitalism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only relevant bit is this:

> He had no compunction in taking the help of the Nazis or the Fascists and later of Imperial Japan

To break this down:

> He had no compunction in taking the help

This is the first section, which just describes him receiving help from.

> of ((the Nazis) or (the Fascists))

He receives help from *the Nazis*, the first noun, and *the Fascists*, the secound noun.

> and later

The "and" here just extends the list of places he got help from. "Later" here refers to the fact that he got (...) at a *later date than* (or *after*) the Nazis and Fascists mentioned above.

> of (Imperial Japan)

So, putting it all together: He had no compunction in taking the help (of (the Nazis - or - the Fascists)) and later: (of Imperial Japan).

Answer (score 3):

It indicates that he took the help of the Nazis first, and then later as in "at a later time" or "at a date after than that of which he took the help of the Nazis" he then also accepted the help of Imperial Japan.